# cannot run kubectl, due to port conflicts but also cannot fix them with solutions online

Tags: ubuntu, kubernetes, google-compute-engine, google-kubernetes-engine, amazon-eks

`error: unable to recognize "xxxxx-pod.yml": Get http://localhost:8080/api?timeout=32s: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:8080: connect: connection refused`,

I tried the solutions available online but none of them really worked.

Comment: can you please share your `xxxxx-pod.yml` file

Comment: It is irrelevant to this anything I try over the server is resulting in the same but I also don’t know the solution

Comment: The first step is to understand the error message. `127.0.0.1` is the TCP loopback device. This means that this address is only valid from inside the machine. Are you logged into the Kubernetes Master via SSH? If not, this address is not valid to access Kubernetes on a network. Look up the URL for our master and use that to set up your tools.

Answer (score 1):

This means your kubeconfig is not correct. It is using the default server URL which is probably not what you intended.

Answer (score 0):

It was due to the flannel issue but I think it is resolved now. I had to put a hold on the versions of kubectl as they upgraded without my knowledge. This worked for me.